# How to remove "^[[m" and "^[[32" characters in vim

Tags: git, vim, command-line-interface, branch

I want to get the list of the names of my merged branches into a file.

```
$ git branch --merged
  fix-typo
* master
  update-readme
```

However, when I write this output into a file and I open it with Vim, I find some unexpected characters:

```
$ git branch --merged > test
$ vim test
```

```
  fix-typo^[[m
* ^[[32mmaster^[[m
  update-readme^[[m
```

What are they and how can I remove the `^[[m` and `^[[32` characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR; Use `--no-color` flag

```sh
git branch --no-color --merged
```

Weird characters you see there are ASCI escape codes for coloring the terminal output. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors
The best way to get rid of them is to ask git to not produce them by using the `--no-color` flag. You will get plain text output then.

Also git should automatically resign from coloring output when it is redirected. At least it works as such in my case. (fish)

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked into it your last sentence and realized that the problem was that I had the git configuration `color.ui=always`. I changed it to `color.ui=auto` and now I don't need the `--no-color` flag.